# XSL: wrap content between given <p> in <div>

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a generated XML file which has content like this:

```
<p stylename='myStyle'/>
<p stylename='otherStyle'> Something </p>
<p stylename='anyotherStyle'> Something else </p>
<p stylename='myStyle'/>
<p stylename='otherStyle'> Something else </p>
...
```

What I would need is to have output looking like this:

```
<DIV stylename='myStyle'>
<p stylename='otherStyle'> Something </p>
<p stylename='anyotherStyle'> Something else </p>
</DIV>
<DIV stylename='myStyle'>
<p stylename='otherStyle'> Something else </p>
...
</DIV>
```

To sum up, I have empty `<p>` tags with stylename 'myStyle' and I need to have all the content between them to be wrapped in a `<DIV>`.
I can't change the XML input and I can use only XSLT 1.0

I have basic knowledge of XSLT but I can't figure out how to do this.
Any thoughts?
Thank you

Comment: Either use sibling recursion or use a key that maps `<xsl:key name="siblings" match="p[normalize-space()]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[not(normalize-space())][1])"/>`, then, when processing the empty `p`s, you can create the `div` wrapper and grab the siblings with `key('siblings', generate-id())`.

Comment: Thank you, I then used solution which was clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used code like below, works exactly as I needed.

```
<xsl:template match="p[@stylename='myStyle']">
<div class="myStyle"><xsl:variable name="divID" select="generate-id(.)"/>
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@stylename='myStyle'][1]) = $divID]">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```